# hide and rename a folder using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, rename

Suppose, I have a link in my website as follows: `www.example.com/test/index.php`.
I want to hide the 'test' folder from visitors  and make it visible  as 'apple' so that when the user types `www.example.com/apple` or `www.example.com/apple/index.php`, it automatically redirects to `www.example.com/test/index.php`. I want to make it possible by editing the .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) apple/$1
```

But, it's not working. Is there anything wrong here? How will I rename the folder?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^test/(.*) apple/$1 [R=301]`.

Comment: will it also work FOR link like this? www.example.com/D/demo/apple/index.php? @BenM

Answer (score 0):

For a PHP file:

#### Example 1

```
RewriteRule ^/?api/([^/]+)?$ "request.php?rquest=$1" [L,QSA]
```

#### Example 2

```
RewriteRule ^/?api/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ "request.php?rquest=$2&ns=$1" [L,QSA]
```

Where `request.php` is a file. It will be be referred `example.com/api/{ns}/{rquest}` in latter and `example.com/api/{rquest}` in former.

If you want to use a folder, as you requested, you may use like the following. Please test it out, as I have not used like this yet.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?apple/([^/]+)?$ "test/index.php?categories=$1" [L,QSA]
```

It is simply a rewrite rule. You define a pattern, and you then match it with what you want it to be rewritten. Simple as that.

Do you want to ignore the slash followed? That is like

`example.com/help/legal/privacy/eula` should be rewritten as `example.com/help.php?path=/legal/privacy/eula`, then you must ignore the `/` in the path followed by `help` in the URL pattern.

You can simply change the regex like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/?help/(.+)?$ "help.php?topic=$1" [L,QSA]
```

So regex uses `(.+)` means, take and step everything and don't stop.

So this is the URL syntax:

```
RewriteRule {regex_of_url_pattern} "{rewrite_into_what}" [OPTIONS ...]
```

---

For more information and examples, please refer

- https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html